# DevExpress ASPxGridView with detail view collapsed dosn't run javascript

Tags: jquery, events, gridview, devexpress, detailview

I have a devexpress gridview where I use a select to make an operation over the data, that is opening another page. This select is replaced with dropkick jquery. It's working perfectly on the loading and the expansion of the detail row, but when I collapse the row I don't find an event like `detail_row_collapsed` to call my script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Just did. If I get a solution I'll post it here to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it using the ClientSideEvent "EndCallback" on the gridview only, calling my script from there.

```
<ClientSideEvents   
                   EndCallback="MyDropkickScript" RowClick="OnRowClick"  DetailRowExpanding="OnDetailRowExpanding" DetailRowCollapsing="OnDetailRowCollapsing"
                   />
```

The problems was by using too much ClientSideEvents in both GridView and DetailView.